# Why won't fsck fix my ext4 partition?

Tags: ext4, fsck, inode

There is a directory on one of my EXT4 partitions that an error, but `fsck` can't seem to fix it.

```
# fsck -ClV -vpf /dev/mapper/enc_vols-home
fsck from util-linux 2.37
[/usr/bin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- /home] fsck.ext4 -vpf -C0 /dev/mapper/enc_vols-home 
Locking disk by /run/fsck/dm-1.lock ... succeeded.
                                                                               
     7541657 inodes used (6.18%, out of 122085376)
       36156 non-contiguous files (0.5%)
        3791 non-contiguous directories (0.1%)
             # of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
             Extent depth histogram: 7516765/3959
   197726286 blocks used (40.49%, out of 488340480)
           0 bad blocks
          17 large files

     6501236 regular files
     1011955 directories
           0 character device files
           0 block device files
           3 fifos
         153 links
       28409 symbolic links (20877 fast symbolic links)
          45 sockets
------------
     7541801 files
Unlocking /run/fsck/dm-1.lock.
#
# mount /dev/mapper/enc_vols-home /mnt/home 
# find /mnt/home/foo/bar > /dev/null
[ 1188.983435] archlinux kernel: EXT4-fs error (device dm-1): ext4_lookup:1707: inode #27922002: comm find: iget: bad extra_isize 32700 (inode size 256)
[ 1188.986732] archlinux kernel: EXT4-fs error (device dm-1): ext4_lookup:1707: inode #27922002: comm find: iget: bad extra_isize 32700 (inode size 256)
find: ‘/mnt/home/foo/bar/foo2/foo3/foo4/foo5/foo6’: Structure needs cleaning
[ 1189.062658] archlinux kernel: EXT4-fs error (device dm-1): ext4_lookup:1707: inode #27922007: comm find: iget: bad extra_isize 17291 (inode size 256)
[ 1189.065903] archlinux kernel: EXT4-fs error (device dm-1): ext4_lookup:1707: inode #27922007: comm find: iget: bad extra_isize 17291 (inode size 256)
find: ‘/mnt/home/foo/bar/foo2/foo3/foo4/foo7’: Structure needs cleaning
```

I've also tried umounting the drive and running `fsck` again, but it doesn't help - it still complains about that folder.

The partition is ext4 on LVM2 on LUKS on a RAID1 (mirror):

```
sdb                 sdb       /dev/sdb                    8:16                 linux_raid_member  
└─md127             md127     /dev/md127                  9:127                crypto_LUKS        
  └─enc_vols        dm-0      /dev/mapper/enc_vols      253:0                  LVM2_member        
    └─enc_vols-home dm-1      /dev/mapper/enc_vols-home 253:1   1015.4G   1.8T ext4               
sdc                 sdc       /dev/sdc                    8:32                 linux_raid_member  
└─md127             md127     /dev/md127                  9:127                crypto_LUKS        
  └─enc_vols        dm-0      /dev/mapper/enc_vols      253:0                  LVM2_member        
    └─enc_vols-home dm-1      /dev/mapper/enc_vols-home 253:1   1015.4G   1.8T ext4
```

Both drives in the array are less than 2 years old and show no errors in SMART, though I have still not run `fsck -c`.

Why isn't `fsck` finding the error, and how can I clean up this directory?

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of e2fsck, currently 1.46.2.  If you are still having problems, best to email linux-ext4@vger.kernel.org.

Comment: @LustreOne it's for some reason not in the output above, but I am indeed running 1.46.2. Thanks for the tip, mailing list was/is going to be my next step.